# GCC vs MSVC class packing and alignment

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, compiler-construction, alignment

Is there a way with compiler flags to create the same memory layout of a base class and a derived class under msvc compared to its equivalent in gcc?  Im using VS2010 and comparing it to GCC 4.1.1

So

```
#if define _MSVC
// window 
DALIGN(A,B) __declspec(align(A)) B
#else
// GCC
DALIGN(A,B) B __attribute__((aligned(A)))
#endif
class A
{ 
  DALIGN(CVector V,16);
  int a;
}
class B : public A
{
  int b;
}
```

A is 16byte aligned making it 0x20(32) 
B is also 16 byte aligned, but is either also 0x20(32) on GCC but on msvc it is 0x30(48)

is there a way to force the msvc to pack the data like GCC is?

Reason for this: I create data and load it directly into the classes on different platforms.  What would really be nice is if I could use the exact same data layout on both platforms.  (Yes endian is the same on both platforms)

Comment: Don't rely on packing to do this.  Use Serialization to create a platform-independent representation of the class.

Comment: That is what I am doing, I have a tool that exports the serialized data, problem is that the alignment/placement of the data is different between the two compilers.  Thus the data can't be shared.  This is working on two other platforms (has been for years) but I just added MSVC(windows) and it breaks on tests for this kind of misalignment of data.

Comment: You cannot just dump the contents of X from &X and expect it to be retrievable. Check out Boost.Serialization at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html.  As a band aid, you might be able to add extra fields to get the padding right on Windows to make these structure alignment correct for reading back but that's brittle and not scalable.

Comment: btw if you want to pursue the padding option you would need to dump the offset of every field of the structure on each platform and then fiddle with pads (macro-ed for Windows only) until the offsets match up.  Ugh.

Comment: I know you can't just dump the contents.  I have a tool which is data driven.  It parses the data description and builds the data according to the description.  It accounts for vtable, alignment, type sizes, and endian.  Problem is that I would like to use the same data across both little endian platforms.

Comment: If you want to control the size and alignment of data structures, you need to make them POD (or standard layout, in the new C++11 terminology).  That rules out inheritance.

Comment: I don't know if it is the correct way but the solution Im currently using in any obj that needs to be align(16), I wrap with #pragma pack(4) and pack(pop)  It seems to cause the alignment to be the same as the GCC alignment for those derived classes.  I have run tests using most of the standard types and everything is located in the class at the correct offset.    Input???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding #pragma pack(push, 4) / #pragma pack(pop)
around the class A and class B succeeded in correctly aligning the data as GCC aligns it.

Note that if the inheritance is extended, it seems like for any required aligned class and forward through the inheritance all require the packing.
Example classes A,B,C,D,E,F
C has aligned members
C,D,E,F all require the packs around them.