# Compiling gcc code in Visual Studio causes error C3646: '__attribute__': unknown override specifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, msvc12

I am getting the following error:

> error C3646: '__attribute__': unknown override specifier

Code:

```
LEMUR_PREALIGN char _stack[ sizeof(_Type) * _Count ] LEMUR_POSTALIGN;
```

Complete error:

> 1>c:\program files\indri\indri 5.9\include\indri\greedy_vector(52): error C3646: '__attribute__': unknown override specifier

Additional info: I am trying to use indri.lib in Visual Studio project.

Comment: Would you mind providing your code working on? It should be [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And your title and question have different error messages.

Comment: Does the `LEMUR_POSTALIGN` mean this? http://www.lemurproject.org/doxygen/lemur/html/lemur-platform_8h.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__attribute__` command is a compiler specific command to gcc. And it is used on line 52 of [this file](http://www.lemurproject.org/doxygen/lemur/html/lemur-platform_8h-source.html) with the [`((align))` command](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html), which:

> Specifies a minimum alignment (in bytes) for variables of the specified type

Visual studio does in fact have a similar alignment command: [`align`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx). But there are two problems:

1. `__declspec(align(#))` does not support the defaulted: `__attribute__ ((aligned))` behavior which will:

> Align a type to the maximum useful alignment for the target machine you are compiling for

2. `__declspec(align(#))` is a prefix. `__attribute__((aligned(#)))` is a suffix. This means that your actual code would need to differ on the placement:

`struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned)); // gcc alignment definition
__declspec(align(16)) strict S { short f[3]; }; // MSVC alignment`

The point here is you'd probably be better off `#ifdef`ing by compiler any line that uses `__attribute__ ((aligned))` and cooking your own `__declspec(align(#))`.

For more info see: [GCC vs MSVC class packing and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302480/gcc-vs-msvc-class-packing-and-alignment)

---

After a bit more study into lemur_platform.h it looks like the code has already done all the above work for you! You'll notice that `#define LEMUR_POSTALIGN   __attribute__ ((aligned))` is wrapped in an `#ifndef WIN32`. So what you need to do is define `WIN32` in your Visual Studio project!

Comment: if i am not wrong, i think win32 is automatically defined in Visual Studio project.
or is there any specific way to define win32?

Comment: @AsimSaeed I think you're thinking of `_WIN32` which is [always defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay). You need to define `WIN32`. I'd recommend using the preprocessor arguments so you can put it in project code rather than in code. To do that use the [\D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) directive.